# Is it possible to call a command inside a thread

Tags: c++, c, multithreading, algorithm

Generally while writing a c/cpp program, if i ever need to execute any bash command for which there is no c library, i fork a child and then do execvp on it by passing a script name.

But i want to know is it possible to call like this in a thread without forking(if forking then there's no advantage of threads), or is there any other way to do this?

**Actual Problem**:

*Background*:
there's a commandline utility called `criu` which can checkpoint a running program and creates a folder containing files for the program state. This command has options to leave the program in running state after creating the checkpoint.

*Goal*: I've to call this utility multiple times periodically(say in a period of 50 milliseconds). Send this checkpoint folder to the destination(i use `rsync` utility to do this) asynchronously which means the program should not wait for the transmission of checkpoint to complete as soon as it creates a checkpoint by calling `criu` utility it resumes for another iteration, wait for another 50 ms and then again makes a call to criu to create a checkpoint.

A diagram will help more to understand the flow of program:
[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/270p4.png) The blue colored execute duration is for say 50 ms. Do SomeTask(4) and execution is in parallel.

*My approach*: see below pseudo code for my design of the program:

```
while(true){

 sleep(50ms) // wait for 50 milliseconds
 
 call criu utility // which takes checkpoint of another running  program.This part is not so much of focus right now, can assume there is something which just creates a folder.

 send the checkpoint to the destination in parallel // using rsync utility for this, so i've no idea how will i build the part where this program will recieve an acknowledgement back and perform another task parallely with the help of threads.

}
```

**Note**: program takes a checkpoint of another running program using pid of that program, mentioning this to remove any confusion.

Please comment below if you want further clarifications. I hope this question is not creating any confusions with the word `criu`, `rsync` command line utilities. you can forget those and just see the flow which is the main problem right now.

*Reason for question statement*:
I've thought of creating threads instead of forking each time i call a command usng bash script inside this c/cpp program as this program is running infintely at some point it system will have a large number of process created and may throw an error of system resources unavailable if use forking. Thtat's why wanted to know if it's possible to call commands inside a thread.

Comment: No; you can't invoke a separate program without forking (or using `posix_spawn()` and its brethren).  Threads are part of a single process; you can't have separate processes running in separate threads of a single process.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks, now can you look into the actual problem  description and help me in designing a  better flow  of the program, i mean to say please suggest any approach with which all this can be incorporated.

Comment: Is there any way by which i can not worry about of so many child processes existing , all of them will  be destroyed after their  task completion even when running in parallel with the parent .

Comment: I don't have any good ideas.  Running the external process (`criu`) 20 times a second doesn't sound good.  I'm not clear if there'd also be 20 `rsync` processes per second.  It sounds as if you need to incorporate the functionality of `criu` into your program.  Your processing must finish reliably in under 20 milliseconds (on the average); otherwise, you accumulate a backlog of work.  I can't judge what's feasible from the information given.

Comment: Before the loop, `fork()` and `wait()` criu, so that you've got one criu finished. Inside the loop, take a time stamp, `fork()` rsync, `fork()` criu, `wait()` on criu, `wait()` on rsync. Take another time stamp. If the time used was less than 50msec, `sleep()` for the remaining time. That way you're running criu and rsync in parallel, but you aren't accumulating a backlog of processes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i think you misunderstood this, i was asking about the design flow,  lets say i'm forking  a child to call `criu`  till then the main thread will wait, and when the checkpoint is created, again i'm forking a child to call `rsync`.  Now how will i implement the receving of acknowldegement part, when a signal/ACK is received the programm will do another task parallely say by creating a thread.  THe child process which calls `rsync` doesn't have shared memory space with parent so it doesn't know what to call when an ACK is received, and  (continued......)

Comment: first of all how the ACK will be received `rsync` client sends the data to `rsync` server running on the other side but the child process doesn't get any ACK to know  when the transmission will be complete.  and  now the problem is if somehow child gets to know that it has received acknowledgment how will it notify parent to perform the other task.  Right now i'm not worried about efficiency, i'm worried about correctness.

Comment: @user3386109 did you look at the diagram, rsync transmit the state captured by criu. so as in pseudo code you will see the main thread will cintinue for another iteration as soon as it calls rsync, i do not get to what part of the problem you proposed the solution?